# mysql query and subquery returns all rows

Tags: mysql

I can't to build this query it returns all rows from table.
I want to select only this records where catid is between 1 and 20 and only these records from interval of 30days.
Seperated both queries working.

```
- SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE uploaded >= DATE_SUB(NOW()
- SELECT id FROM `movies` WHERE (catid BETWEEN 1 AND 20)
```

Whole query with subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE uploaded >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) IN(SELECT id FROM `movies` WHERE (catid BETWEEN 1 AND 20))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM `movies` 
WHERE uploaded >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
AND catid BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

Comment: Works perfect therefore I don't need from subquery :)